# The derivationof sine to cosine

Tags: wave-equation

I am new to mathematics somehow, and I know that:

> $\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}= \cos x$

But I can't understand this:

> $\frac{d (a \sin(\omega.t))}{dt} = a.\omega\cos(\omega.t)$
>
> > where $a$ is the peak of the wave and $\omega$ is $2\pi f$ (where $f$ is frequency)

Could anyone please explain it for me?

Comment: What do you know about derivatives?

Comment: Have you seen the chain rule?

Comment: Just a little, I studied a small amount of information about it two years ago, and this year I saw this equation in my physics book.

Comment: As Sylvester said, you should apply the chain rule. It is a basic rule that you should know about derivatives. Take a time to learn about it.

Comment: what do you know about mathematics? tell us!

Comment: @PushkarSoni I studied a high school stuff about two years ago, this year I have to study physics and found that one of the topics I study is based on derivatives. And, to be honest, I don't remember so much about it.

Comment: good luck buddy :)

Comment: @PushkarSoni, Thank you, my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{d (a \sin(\omega.t))}{dt} = \frac{d(a.\sin(\omega t))}{d(\omega t)}.\frac{d(\omega t)}{dt} = a . \frac{d(\sin(\omega t))}{d(\omega t)}.\frac{\omega.d(t)}{dt}=a.\cos(\omega t).\omega$.

Here this type of above method is known as chain rule .Explore it more!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here chain rule is used.

$\frac {d}{dt} (\sin (\omega.t)) = \cos (\omega.t). \frac {d}{dt} (\omega.t)$

= $ \cos (\omega.t). \omega. \frac{d}{dt} t$

= $ \cos (\omega.t). \omega . 1$

= $\omega. \cos (\omega.t)$